# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType error while downloading attachment

Tags: python-3.x, email

Iam getting this error while trying to download a attachment file from gmail account.

```
fp = open(filename, 'wb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Earlier i could make fluent downloads from this script but now having this error. Please help me out what's wrong with the script?

```
import imaplib, email
import io
#log in and select the inbox
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('youmailid@gmail.com', 'yourpassword')
mail.select('testing')

#get uids of all messages
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'ALL') 
uids = data[0].split()
print (uids)
#read the lastest message
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', uids[-1], '(RFC822)')
m = email.message_from_string(data[0][1].decode())

if m.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None: continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        fp = open(filename, 'wb')
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
        fp.close()
        print (f'{filename} saved!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `filename` is `None`

Add the condition

```
if filename is None: continue
```

after the line

```
filename = part.get_filename()
```